# Put nils in front of array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a couple of arrays that I want to put nils into so that my indexing will
be further into the array based on how I use the aray. Is there a faster, more efficient and elegant way ?

```
(1..@epgroup_overide_count.to_i).each do 
    @grp['Overides'].unshift(nil)
    @grp['channel_overides'].unshift(nil)
end
```

Comment: Elegant way for inelegant problem? I don't think so :)

Comment: do u have data in arrays? or u want initialize new arrays with nil?

Answer (score 2):

`#unshift` takes a splatted arg list to prepend multiple elements, so:

```
@group['Overides'].unshift(*([nil]*@epgroup_override_count.to_i))
```

This will do it (similar for your second one)

---

Breaking down the one liner:

`[nil] * @epgroup_override_count.to_i`

Multiplying an array by a number duplicates the array that many times, but as a single flat array (`[1,2,3]*3 #=> [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]`). One thing to be aware of is that if the array has variable references, it creates multiple references to the same objects, not duplicates.

`*(above_multiplied_array)`

using the splat operator to spread the array into the args of the method

`arr.unshift(multiple, args, here)`

By using the splat operator, we spread the array into multiple args to `#unshift`. When `#unshift` is given multiple args, it prepends all of them to the array, which is the desired result.

Comment: My god, it looks awful! But hey, it's a one-liner. Cheers and +1 for that :)

Comment: @JimDeville can you bit explain your one-liner?

Comment: Will that execute faster or is it just shorthand ?

Comment: it is faster I see, just curious ..

    x = []

    (1..100000).each do |n|
      x << n*2
    end

    y = x.dup

    start = Time.now
    x.unshift(*([nil] * 3000))
    p Time.now - start

    start = Time.now
    (1..3000).each do
      y.unshift nil 
    end 
    p Time.now - start

    0.016
    0.281

Comment: I see how the other * works, cool

`irb(main):001:0> x=[5,6,7]
=> [5, 6, 7]
irb(main):002:0> x.unshift([7,8,8])
=> [[7, 8, 8], 5, 6, 7]
irb(main):003:0> x.unshift(*[7,8,8])
=> [7, 8, 8, [7, 8, 8], 5, 6, 7]`

Comment: @TheMiddleMan Good idea, expanded the one liner to explain it

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below:

```
 @grp['Overides'] +=([nil]*@epgroup_override_count.to_i).flatten
 @grp['channel_overides'] += ([nil]*@epgroup_override_count.to_i).flatten

 or

 nil_array = ([nil]*@epgroup_override_count.to_i).flatten
 @grp['Overides'] += nil_array
 @grp['channel_overides'] += nil_array
```